# Firewall for Windows, which controls in/out data flow

Tags: windows, windows-10, firewall, dataflow

I am searching for a firewall for Windows, which can control data flow in and out of my PC.
I am not talking about inbound/outbound connection but about data flow.

[Sorry, I don't know technical terms. Visit: https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=432679 to understand what I mean by data flow]

Comment: Why do you believe you need this?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I use apps which use microphone, I don't want them to upload audio, only use speech recognition already available on PC. Also, I don't want to restrict their internet.

Comment: "Data flow" always goes both ways, for pretty much every single program out there. Browsers send HTTP requests and receive a web page as a response, and the like. It's always 2-way.

Comment: @Alejandro Oh! I got it. But, What can be the solution to this. "I use apps which use microphone, I don't want them to upload audio, only use speech recognition already available on PC. Also, I don't want to restrict their internet."

Comment: @TontyTon But problem still is that "upload audio" is still "internet access", from the outside there is no difference, specially when using HTTPS, encryption even prevents to peek at what's doing. The most similar thing I can think of are [stateful firewalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall) or [deep packet inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection). The practical solution to your problem I would give would be "if you don't trust a program, either deprive it of internet access or uninstall it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the informations you provided, you probably need something more than just firewall. I once looked at a very nice project on github called [WFN](https://github.com/wokhansoft/WFN) that is aiming to extended firewall behaviour, yet itself it's not firewall.

Comment: It is just for monitoring, not to block data flow.